# Big text files in python

Tags: python

I have to write some Python code to read a file in the following format:

```
<doc> 
Hello Word
</doc>
<doc>
Hello blah blah
</doc>
```

Then I have to count how many of those tags contains a determined word.

For example, if I'm searching for the word blah it should return 1, and if I'm searching for the word Hello, it should return 2.

Also, is there a way to do it efficiently? The files are pretty big (approximately 250mb of text).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples

Comment: Some general advice: Don't worry about the efficiency until you have something that works.

Answer (score -1):

Load the file and read it line by line, incrementing occurrences.

```
# Returns how many times s_string shows up in doc
def search_for( s_string, doc):
    count = 0
    with open(doc) as rfile:
        for line in rfile:
            if(line.find(s_string) > -1):
                count = count + 1
    return count
```

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before but here is a function that will get it done.